# what is the difference between these two ul tags

Tags: html, css

something driver me crazy here 
i have a big HTML template which i can't post but the problem is that when i write ul tag like this everything works find

```
<ul><li>something</li><li>something</li><li>something</li></ul>
```

but when i write it like this i got +4 pixel i don't know from where

```
<ul>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
</ul>
```

when i use the second method i'm sure that i have no extra space somewhere but i think it's from the "enter" between them

Any solution? css maybe

::Extra info

i found that the problem comes from closing and starting li tag this worked out

```
<ul>
<li>
something
</li><li>
something
</li><li>
something
</li>
</ul>
```

any idea ?

Comment: where do you get +4 pixel? At the left?

Comment: where does the pixels appear, could it be some special character?

Comment: Use the firebug plugin for firefox and check which style is giving you this margin.

Comment: don't know it just ruin my design, i just add 4 pixel to its parent everything goes right

Comment: Which IDE you are using. have you checked in different IDEs too?

Comment: all of them IE8 // FF 3.6 // Chrome

Comment: both ways are exactly same. It not due to "enter" bwtween them.

Comment: everything looks fine on firebug

Comment: Check the source in the browser, maybe something is generating <br/>s

Comment: @nvl when i removes that "enters" everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would start by using a reset CSS like this [one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably noticing such gap because you are using CSS to make an horizontal menu; when making `<li>` inline elements white space between them is not ignored.

Comment: What didn't work? I didn't propose anything. Is my guess correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what cause the problem, but you can solve it using CSS. Write a style for li element and specify the proper margin.

Comment: Try to apply the style to both ul and li:
li
{
    margin:0;
}
ul
{
    margin:0;
}
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're noticing is the 'feature' of (x)html collapsing whitespace into a single space. Most of the time this isn't too much of a problem, but for a horizontal menu it's an irritation.

There are two options available to deal with this (in addition to your first example):

```
<ul>
<li>something</li
><li>something</li
><li>something</li>
</ul>
```

(Note that the first two `</li>` tags aren't closed until the following line.)

```
<ul>
<li>something</li><!-- hiding the whitespace
--><li>something</li><!-- hiding the whitespace again
--><li>something</li>
</ul>
```

Of the two options I prefer the first, it doesn't throw up any errors, validating quite happily under xhtml 1.0 strict. It's not an ideal situation, but it's slightly better than trying to put a whole list into a single line of (x)html.